# How to display different content on the same page using different URLS

Tags: javascript, url

I'm using wordpress. I have query string functionally that displays the content in the correct language.

Example urls

```
example.com/terms/?lang=en
example.com/terms/?lang=es
example.com/terms/?lang=fr
example.com/terms/?lang=db
```

The code below grabs the query string value[lang code] and the API uses it to show the correct language.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">   
  var langCodeSearch = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  var langCode = Object.fromEntries(langCodeSearch.entries());

              
   Api.Initialized.then(function() {
    Api.LoadContent(["https://url-to-api-that-has-content.json"], langCode.lang //**language declaration need to happen here**);
              });
</script>
```

The above code works great but would it be possible to have the same functionally but using the following URL structure?

```
example.com/terms/en
example.com/terms/es
example.com/terms/fr
example.com/terms/gb
```

I want to display content based on the last part of the URLs.

Comment: Yes, but that means you will need to have some kind of server-side redirect, since those URLs actually will navigate to specific pages instead of to the same page with a different query string.

Comment: As addition to the previous comment this is usually a very small change but it depends on the webserver. For Apache httpd you can use a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @jabaa any examples you can point me to?

Comment: @Terry So the server side redirect will allow me to use urls like example.com/terms/es ?

Comment: [How to rewrite url with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564133/how-to-rewrite-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: Many CMS handle this problem with a preconfigured htaccess file to achieve the same behavior you want. [Here](https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess) is the htaccess of Joomla.

Comment: [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes)